# Run java program on system terminal directly from intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm experimenting with `Terminal Control Escape Sequences` in my java program that allows me two print a string at any x,y coordinate on my terminal. But I can't test this on intelliJ's terminal.

I've already seen solution on other thread where they say to copy the command from intelliJ's console and then paste it on system terminal to run it, but it is very tedious and also I've to build every time on intelliJ first, and then try it out on system terminal.

Is there a way to for intelliJ to open system terminal and run program when I press run shortcut?

Comment: Set up a new debug target.  I have used one called "Bash" in the past that creates a new terminal window to launch the app in (you have to use IntelliJ $ params to set additional command line parameters).  If you are on windows, there may be something equivalent.  Look in "Run | Edit Configurations..." menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it out of the box, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19938 and the linked requests.

You can create an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) that will spawn a Terminal window for your OS and start your app in this window. All the required macros for the paths/classes are available in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look into external tool and try to come up with one for my use case.

Comment: @Tanmay_vijay have you succeed?